# AjaxFileUpload -- UploadComplete event not firing on test server

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I can upload files in my development environment -- VS2013 VB.Net -- but when I move it to either test or production server the `UploadComplete` event doesn't fire. I updated the `<handlers>` and `<httpHandlers>` sections in both Web.config files. I can tell the method isn't invoked because I have it write to a log file when it does. I have assigned read/write permissions to my destination upload directory. I am using AjaxControlToolkit v16.1.0.0 My Test server is Windows Server 2012 R2, Production server: Windows Server 2008 R2

Any ideas what to try next?

**EDIT:** Sorry, it was not my intention to project an air of mystery. I didn't append code because the code works here on my PC in the Dev Env, so I figured it wasn't the issue -- more likely an IIS or Server thing... But the ASPX file has this:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
    AllowedFileTypes="xlsx,xls" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
    MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" IsInFileUploadPostBack="false"
    ClearFileListAfterUpload="true" />
```

The server-side event handler, not being invoked, is declared as:

```
Private Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadComplete
```

And the Web.config contains handlers:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```

and

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false"/>
  <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: posting your code?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post